# Turn on opacity for div on mousehover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to turn on the div `#overlay` `opacity: 1` when I move mouse over div `#header`. Also it's important that `#header` remains relative, so it won't affect that.

I tried to do this with jQuery (code below), but it did not work at all.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Overlay Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#header").hover(function(){
            $("#overlay").fadeTo(200, 1);
        }, function(){
            $("#overlay").fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: #7a7a7a;
    }
    #header {
        padding: 20px 60px;
        position:relative;
        height:auto;
        width: auto;
        background: #f6f6f6;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    #content {
        padding: 60px;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 1;
        background: #D1D1D1;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
    #overlay {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        opacity:0;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 5;

    </style>
</head>

    <body>
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header menu area</h1>
</div>
<div id="content"><h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h3></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tuuni/o5pLuvr1/2/

This is how I want the header to look like if I move mouse over it:

[image]

Comment: to use jquery, you need to load it ;) https://jsfiddle.net/s3hg4f2b/

Comment: Use `:hover` in CSS instead.

Comment: @SLaks I can't use :hover with tilde in CSS because the div needs to be below page, if you ref to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the JSFiddle and nor the code you included in your question will work, but they don't work for different reasons. The JSFiddle doesn't work because you haven't included the jQuery library. But otherwise, it should work. But let's focus on the code you provided. Let's look at your code with the less relevant portions omitted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Other Tags -->
    <script>
      $("#header").hover(
        function() {
          $("#overlay").fadeTo(200, 1);
        },
        function() {
          $("#overlay").fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
            $(this).hide();
          });
        }
      );
    </script>
    <!-- Other Tags -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Header menu area</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`$("#header", ...)` runs before the content in the body is created in the DOM, so the hover event listener can't attach to anything. You can fix this by wrapping it all in a `$(document).ready()` call, as shown below. This waits for the body to be created in the DOM before attaching the hover event listener. You can [read more at the jQuery docs site](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#header").hover(
    function() {
      $("#overlay").fadeTo(200, 1);
    },
    function() {
      $("#overlay").fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Yes, you where right on.

It's possible to load window onload also i think:
    window.onload=function(){
      
  $("#header").hover(function(){
   $("#overlay").fadeTo(200, 1);
  }, function(){
   $("#overlay").fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
    $(this).hide();
   });
  });

    }